# Swift How to break an array of objects into an array of arrays?

Tags: swift

I have an array of purchase objects [Purchase] defined as:

```
struct Purchase {
    let count: Int
    let food: String
}
```

How can I get turn this array of purchases into an array of arrays of purchases with the same count (Int)?

For example:

```
let input: [Purchase(count: 2, food: "popcorn"), Purchase(count: 3, food: "popcorn"),  Purchase(count: 2, food: "soda"),
            Purchase(count: 2, food: "popcorn"), Purchase(count: 2, food: "soda")]

output: [[Purchase]] = [[Purchase(count: 2, food: "popcorn"), Purchase(count: 2, food: "soda"),
          Purchase(count: 2, food: "popcorn"), Purchase(count: 2, food: "soda")], [Purchase(count: 3, food: "soda")]
```

Comment: Do you look for specific transformation logic or you just want to make each element trunk into an array of one element?

Comment: You can simply do this: `let output = Array(Dictionary(grouping: input){$0.count}.values)`

Comment: `Purchase(count: 3, food: "soda")` is not contained in `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the comments but it can look a little cleaner.

```swift
Dictionary(grouping: input, by: \.count).map(\.value)
```